# Dropping to cron like environment for debug purposes?

Tags: linux, shell, cron

Cron scripts are executed in "limited" environment, PATH and co are very restrained.

How can I emulate this env setting from interactive shell so that I could debug scripts that work great from user shell bug fail on the cron shell

Answer (score 2):

I found this nice [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2135478/471547) on SO. One of the answers suggest to get the environment variables using `env` and directing the output to a text file in a cron job. Then, you can "import" the same variables in your current shell.